# Record ambient noise without voices

Tags: audio-recording

There's lots of information about getting rid of ambient sound to focus on voice in recordings - what about the opposite? I want to capture ambient noise in a specific environment (a place of business), but for legal reasons, can't capture voices/conversations (at least not in understandable form). What would be the best approach for this?

The ultimate use for this is for sound processing and audio classification in a machine learning model, so it doesn't matter if the voices are there distorting the sound in some way, just as long as they are not understandable.

Comment: Get the people to leave; or be far enough away that they're unintelligible over the ambient. As you didn't tell us what this specific environment is, it's hard to suggest anything else.

Comment: Updated the question - this is a place of business, so we can't ask people to leave. The ambient noise of people moving around is largely what we're trying to capture

Comment: You're gonna need their co-operation at some point. Tell them you're doing a wild track & you need nothing intelligible on tape, but you do need their normal activity otherwise. That's how the sound recordist would do it for a movie, but then again, the others in that situation would know what a wild track is & what it's for, so you may need a bit more explanation.

Comment: Maybe cut the recording into 1s slices and shuffle them randomly?

Comment: My 2 cents: just cheat! Find an empty place that kinda looks like the one you need to capture the ambiance from (similar volumes, similar materials), gather a bunch of people and instruct them to talk the Sims and to pretend to work.

Comment: It depends on the frequency of the sounds you're trying to get, but how about EQ-ing out the voice frequency?